# jQuery AJAX Requests in loop Array issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, loops

I've got some AJAX requests in a for loop. The loop steps through an array of URLs and sends requests to all of them, checks for something on each of the pages, and then pages containing the right data will have some data written to an array. The array is a 'global' variable.

The loops works fine. The requests work fine. The array isn't working properly. The done() function for request 1 will push to the array, but the next done() will just overwrite. This consistently happens where done() calls in rapid succession will overwrite sections of the array instead of adding to it. I don't know why this is happening.

I understand the AJAX calls come back in odd orders and timings, but I thought my use of array.push() would get around the need for specifying index's. What's going on?

```
var globalArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < URLList.length; i++)
    {
        (function (i) {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: URLList[i],
                cache: false
            }).done(function(html)
            {
                if (html.indexOf('someString') != -1)
                {
                    globalArray.push(URLList[i]);
                }
            });
        })(i);
    }
```

So basically, even if the second done() triggers after the first done(), the second done's array.push() will pretend like the array is empty. I don't know why it's not checking each time.

Comment: if (html.indexOf('someString') !=)    probably missing a -1  ==>>  if (html.indexOf('someString') != -1).  Also I don't see why you need function (i) - just have the code in the for loop and reference I directly. The function adds nothing.

Comment: My bad. The -1 is already in my code. I just deleted it during transfer by accident. It's in a function because it doesn't work without it. I can't remember exactly why. Alas, the issue is with the array, not the loop.

Comment: Is globalarray correctly defined?  var globalArray = [];  ??

Comment: Also does URLList[i] really have a href property ? It looks like its an array of string from the ajax call ?

Comment: Once again, my mistake. My code is slightly different - I've simplified the version here. it won't make a difference.

Comment: SO you need to debug whats happening, either using console.log (f12 to see console) or just put alerts in there. And the function is still not necessary (if its not working its not because it needs a function)

Comment: Why don't you send URLList[i] as param instead of index "i"? It means, instead function (i) use function (href) and in the loop globalArray.push(href);.

Comment: I have done plenty of debugging, that's why I know there's the issue.

Comment: The reason it's in a function is because done() needs to know what the value of i was when the AJAX was called. If done() is called 10 seconds after the AJAX is initialised, i will be at its maximum value and all of the done() functions will have i of the same value.

Comment: Ahh ok yes. Now try adding a .fail function as here http://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/uQQ83/

Comment: Nothing fails. I've put in a console.log() that shows each page that meets criteria. It's a lot more than end up in the array.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint at ```globalArray.push(URLList[i]);``` and see if its being hit as expected?

Comment: It's being called, but it keeps judging its own array length wrong and thus overwriting itself. I have a long list of console.logs that show that each done() call thinks the array.length is 0 or 1, and they then keep writing to the same index even though there's time delays between the calls.

Comment: Put some more console.logs on either side of `globalArray.push`, like `console.log(i, globalArray.length, URLList[i]);` and see what is happening.  push() should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improvement for @Varrinder 's answer

```
var URLList = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
var ajaxResulstArray = [];

makeRequest();

function makeRequest() {

    var urlToRequest = URLList.shift();

    if (urlToRequest != undefined) {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: urlToRequest, cache:false 
        }).done(function(html) {
            if (html.indexOf("someString") != -1) {
                ajaxResulstArray.push(urlToRequest);
            }
        }).always(makeRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope im not completly missing the point here.

I'd try `Array.shift()`

Something like below:

```
var URLList = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
var ajaxResulstArray = [];

makeRequest();

function makeRequest() {

    var urlToRequest = URLList.shift();

    if (urlToRequest != undefined) {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: urlToRequest, cache:false 
        }).done(function(html) {
            if (html.indexOf("someString") != -1) {
                ajaxResulstArray.push(urlToRequest);
            }
            makeRequest();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: All of the correct pages are being queried, and using console.log I can see each one that 'succeeds', but not all of the 'successful' queries get written to my global array when they should, because the push() keeps overwriting itself. That's the issue.

Comment: Perhaps then change this:     globalArray.push(URLList[i]);  to this    globalArray[i] = URLList[i];    then you have your unique index i so theres no overwriting possible.

Comment: I can't do that. Not every i will be a successful page, so the array may have huge gaps between indexes

Comment: Yes but just try it and then we can see if its a step in the right direction. I think its unlikely that push would overwrite so lets get to proving that first.

Comment: Yes, that works. All values are now put into the array. Even if I then declared a global integer, I'll hit the same wall where each done call will misinterpret it.

Answer (score 0):

I have declared a global integer.

So far, this now seems to work. I can only surmise that push() takes too long to figure things out. Incidentally, in my console.log I also check the globalArray.length. Surprisingly, it doesn't seem to keep up very well with the globalArrayIndex method I'm not using. I guess .length is really slow, so many quick succession done() calls caused the issue.

```
var globalArray = [];
var globalArrayIndex = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < URLList.length; i++)
    {
        (function (i) {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: URLList[i],
                cache: false
            }).done(function(html)
            {
                if (html.indexOf('someString') != -1)
                {
                    globalArray[globalArrayIndex] = (URLList[i]);
                    globalArrayIndex++;
                }
            });
        })(i);
    }
```